# How to access photos from actual device using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Currently I am using this code:

```
@IBAction func selectPicture(sender: UIButton) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary){
        var imag = UIImagePickerController()
        imag.delegate = self
        imag.sourceType = .Camera;
        imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        imag.allowsEditing = false
        imag.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        self.presentViewController(imag, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But when I run it on the `iPad` of `iPhone` device it asks me only for the camera permission and I don't have the possibility to choose a photo from any album/camera roll.

What can I do so I can access the photos from the device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the wrong `sourceType`:

```
imag.sourceType = .Camera;
```

Change that to:

```
imag.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum;
```

or

```
imag.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
```

The constants are defined in [UIImagePickerControllerSourceType Enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) and the definition is like:

> `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType`
>
> The source to use when picking an image or when determining available
>   media types. Declaration
>
> **Swift**
>
> ```
> enum UIImagePickerControllerSourceType : Int
> {
>     case PhotoLibrary
>     case Camera
>     case SavedPhotosAlbum
> }
> ```
>
> **Constants**
>
> `PhotoLibrary`
>
> Specifies the device’s photo library as the source for the image picker controller.
>
> `Camera`
>
> Specifies the device’s built-in camera as the source for the image picker controller. Indicate the specific camera you want (front or
>   rear, as available) by using the cameraDevice property.
>
> `SavedPhotosAlbum`
>
> Specifies the device’s Camera Roll album as the source for the image picker controller. If the device does not have a camera,
>   specifies the Saved Photos album as the source.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> A given source may not be available on a given device because the
>   source is not physically present or because it cannot currently be
>   accessed.